# Where can I store a password for db to keep it secure configuring ormconfig.json for typeorm?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

This question is about `typeorm` package for Node.js app.
I would like to ask if there is a way to somehow "insert" sensitive data to `ormconfig.json`
like password and username in `typeorm` config file? I thought that it can be stored in `process.env`, but I can't access it in `.json` files like in `.js`. Are there any other ideas?  Or maybe can I setup `typeorm` not only in `ormconfig.json` file?

```
 {
    "type": "postgres",
    "host": "host",
    "port": 5432,
    "username": "test",
    "password": "test",
    "database": "test",
    "synchronize": true,
    "logging": false,
    "entities": [
       "src/entity/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "migrations": [
       "src/migration/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "subscribers": [
       "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
    ]
 }
```

Comment: Indeed, you have a bunch of other options apart from the `json` such as a `js` file instead or environment variables. Have a look at https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/using-ormconfig.md

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather difficult answer. There is no real clear winner over the other per se as they are both helpful in different ways. You can have nested data with `config.json`, but on the other hand, you can also have a cleaner data structure with `.env`

Some thing also to note is that you never want to commit these files to source control (git, svc etc).

**Note:**
If you are a beginners and you want to get it started really quick, I would recommend json.

How to set the environment variables and the differences between a windows environment and a linux one. It gets complex when using Docker and K8S.
But, I would recommend `environment variables` for a much evolved architecture and DevOps.

create `sample.env` or `sample.config.json` which you can rename(can use the same as development settings) and don't store production config and reuse the same in production.

This is important so you can get started as you are not storing them.

Comment: Where is the best place for setting ```environment variables``` in Linux?

Comment: In the project root file, with file name `.env`,
Add `.env` to `.gitignore`

Comment: Does that solution require any extra libraries?

Comment: `dotenv`, https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv
But only for development, or if you are running node.js.  

If you are using `docker-compose` you can directly take it if the `Dockerfile` is in the same directory. https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/